# passing proper arguments to application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

An application controller method requires two arguments `generate_municipal_withins(municipal, radius)` but in a separate controller action, calling this method is yielding

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)):
```

from

```
@municipals.each do |municipal|
  generate_municipal_withins(municipal: municipal, radius: 70)
```

My assumption is that it is the former for if this is modified to `generate_municipal_withins(municipal: municipal, 70)` the same error is generated.

Thus it appears the member of the collection is not being passed as an argument.  How should the syntax be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the method definition, it tells the method is expecting to be called with two arguments, but you're using a single hash in:

```
generate_municipal_withins(municipal: municipal, radius: 70)
```

Doing `method(municipal: municipal, radius: 70)`, is the same as `method({municipal: municipal, radius: 70})`, which is a single argument being a hash.

If your method is defined to use keyword arguments, then you could use the version shown in your question, but for that the method should be written as:

```
generate_municipal_withins(municipal:, radius:)
  ...
end
```

Try passing just `municiapl` and `70`:

```
generate_municipal_withins(municipal, 70)
```

Comment: That's actually how I started out.  then I decided to get explicit (I have the same typo for the object that has generated its set of errors).  Serendipitous way of learning a different way to do somehting equivalent.